# Kubernetes: Kube-DNS vs. CoreDNS

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and looking for a better understanding of the difference between Kube-DNS and CoreDNS.

As I understand it the recommendation is to use the newer CoreDNS rather than the older Kube-DNS.

I have setup a small cluster using `kubeadm` and now I am a little confused about the difference between CoreDNS and Kube-DNS.

Using `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` I can see that I have two CoreDNS pods running.

However using `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces` I also see that I have a service named `kube-dns` running in the `kube-system` namespace. When I inspect that with `kubectl describe svc/kube-dns -n kube-system` I can see that the `kube-dns` service links to coredns.

I am now wondering if I am actually running both kube-dns and coredns. Or else, why is that service called `kube-dns` and not `core-dns`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have K8S 1.12. Do a describe of the dns pod.

> kubectl describe pod coredns-576cbf47c7-hhjrs --namespace=kube-system | grep -i "image:"
>
> Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.2

Looks like coredns is running. According to the documentation CoreDNS is default from K8S 1.11. For previous installations it's kube-dns.

The image is what important, rest are metadata (names, labels etc).

According to the K8S blog [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/10/coredns-ga-for-kubernetes-cluster-dns/).

> In Kubernetes 1.11, CoreDNS has reached General Availability (GA) for DNS-based service discovery, as an alternative to the kube-dns addon. This means that CoreDNS will be offered as an option in upcoming versions of the various installation tools. In fact, the kubeadm team chose to make it the default option starting with Kubernetes 1.11.

Also, see this link for [more](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/#installing-kube-dns-instead-of-coredns-with-kubeadm) info.

Comment: Is the corresponding service also named `kube-dns` on your side?

Comment: Yes. This has been done for the sake of compatibility. The existing clients can still use `kube-dns` for invoking the service after moving from kube-dns to CoreDNS.